# Ruby - How to find a directory whose name is a number

Tags: ruby

If I have directory structure like this

```
MyDir
  + Cars
  + Bicycles
  + 8
  + Devices
  + Movies
```

How do I find directory whose name is a number in MyDir above?  In this example, that directory is directory '8' but it could be '4', '7', '103', '17', ... or any other numeric value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 (Dir['MyDir/*']-Dir['MyDir/*[^0-9]*'])
```

or

```
 Dir.entries('MyDir').reject {|d| /\D/ =~ d}
```

In both examples, an array of all directory entries is constructed, and then those are dropped which have a non-digit in their name.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed, full path to the directory with numeric name.  The 2nd suggestion returns only numeric directory name, the first one returns the whole path to that directory which is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, something like this:

```
Dir.foreach('/path/to/MyDir').grep_v(/\D/)
```

(Improved, following Stefan's suggestion)

Comment: Or `.grep(/\d/)` :)

Comment: @Gerry No. That would match directories like `8abc`.

Comment: Nice use of `grep_v`. You might want to substitute `Dir.entries` with `Dir.foreach`. The former returns an array, the latter an enumerator.

Comment: Thank you.  This works but it returns only the folder name (8).  I need full path including that folder name.  Thanks